# System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'host'.'

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting the below error when connect postgresql from asp.net core application.

> System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'host'.'

Connection string:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Host=localhost;Database=MyDB;Username=postgres;Password=pwd;  Pooling=true"
```

[image]

Comment: Use `Server` instead of `Host`.

Comment: I have tried this. I am getting error for every key. for port, username and password

Comment: Can't tell from your code snippet above, but perhaps you had the same error as I did: went back to look at my code and realized I was still loading the SQL Server driver and dialect on accident, instead of NpgsqlDriver and Postgresql83Dialect. SQL Server driver of course does not have a concept of "host" or the other keys in a PG-style connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Create a little console application and use NpgSql to try and connect using the same connection string.

Add the  [npgsql package from nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/) and try the "getting started" snippet from here [npgsql getting started](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/) using your conn string